# How do I print out an ArrayList of class objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, getter, println

So I'm trying to write a getter method for the following class:

```
public class Birthday {
    private String bdayKid;
    private int age;
    private boolean gift;
    
    public Birthday(String bdayKid, int age, boolean gift) {
        this.bdayKid = bdayKid;
        this.age = age;
        this.gift = gift;
    }
    
    private ArrayList<Birthday> bdays = new ArrayList<Birthday>();
}
```

it's a simple class with uncomplicated variables, but I think I got lost writing the method :( So far I have the following:

```
public ArrayList<Birthday> getBirthdays() {
        Birthday bdays;        
        Iterator<Birthday> it = bdays.iterator();

        for (Birthday bday : bdays) {
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                bdays += it.next();
            }
        return bdays;
        }
    }
```

what I'm TRYING(!) to do is to print out the ArrayList eventually but honestly I just got so confused. So if anybody could help me or tell me where I went wrong I'd be super grateful! 
One of the error messages I'm receiving is for `return bdays;`: "incompatible types: Birthday cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList"

Comment: This is multiple questions. You're trying to return a `Birthday` from a method that's declared as returning an `ArrayList<Birthday>`. To print *out* a list of `Birthday` you'd iterate and print each one individually (assuming you have a reasonable `toString` implementation).

Comment: You need to write a toString() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Birthday` class structure is good for *creating* birthdays. The list of birthdays `private ArrayList<Birthday> bdays = new ArrayList<Birthday>();` is something that should be placed outside of your `Birthday` class.

**Birthday.java**

```
public class Birthday {
    private String bdayKid;
    private int age;
    private boolean gift;
    
    public Birthday(String bdayKid, int age, boolean gift) {
        this.bdayKid = bdayKid;
        this.age = age;
        this.gift = gift;
    }
}
```

When you start your program, you can create your list of birthdays that you want to print.

**MyBirthdayProgram.java**

```
public class MyBirthdayProgram{
   public static void main(String []args) {
      //get your list of birthdays that you want to print
      ArrayList<Birthday> bdays = getBirthdays();
      //print your list of birthdays
      printBirthdays(bdays);
   }

   //This method will return a list of birthdays
   public ArrayList<Birthday> getBirthdays() {     
      //initialize your list of birthdays so that you can add to it
      ArrayList<Birthday> bdays = new ArrayList<Birthday>();

      //create a birthday
      Birthday birthday1 = new Birthday("nasrot", 10, true);
      //remember to add the birthday to your list of birthdays
      bdays.add(birthday1);

      //create a birthday
      Birthday birthday2 = new Birthday("redwingsdan", 8, false);
      //remember to add the birthday to your list of birthdays
      bdays.add(birthday2);

      //remember to return your list of birthdays!
      return bdays;
   }

   //This method will print a list of birthdays
   public void printBirthdays(ArrayList<Birthday> bdays) {    
      //iterate through each birthday and print out the result 
      for (Birthday bday : bdays) {
         System.out.println(bday);
      }
   }
}
```

In order to get `System.out.println(bday);` to work the way you expect, you should do what Aristotle suggested and print out your birthdays by overriding a `toString()` method in the `Birthday` class.

Here's a useful article about overriding the `toString()` method https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/

**Birthday.java**

```
public class Birthday {
    private String bdayKid;
    private int age;
    private boolean gift;
    
    public Birthday(String bdayKid, int age, boolean gift) {
        this.bdayKid = bdayKid;
        this.age = age;
        this.gift = gift;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "Happy birthday to " + this.bdayKid + "! "
              + this.bdayKid + " is " + this.age + " years old. "
              + this.bdayKid + " is " + (this.gift ? "" : "not ") + " getting a gift.";
    }
}
```

Your print result using this code would be:

`Happy birthday to nasrot! nasrot is 10 years old. nasrot is getting a gift.`

`Happy birthday to redwingsdan! redwingsdan is 8 years old. redwingsdan is not getting a gift.`

Comment: thank you so much, it's working flawlessly now!! :] i don't know if i should ask this in a separate post, but how would i go about this if i wanted to use a scanner to create a birthday? as in, using the scanner input to add to my arraylist?

Answer (score 1):

I got a bit confused, to be honest.

a) So let's get to the case where you want to print (console) :

override a toString() method, so you can print the birthdays the way you want.

```
public void getBirthdays() {
      for (Birthday bday : bdays) {
         System.out.println(bday);
      }
}
```

b) the case where you want to return the bdays arraylist :

```
public ArrayList<Birthday> getBirthdays() {
    return this.bdays;
}
```

I hope that I helped a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Birthday danny = new Birthday("danny","22-10-2011", 10, true);
    Birthday ryan = new Birthday("ryan", "10-05-2013", 8, false);
    ArrayList<Birthday> birthdaysKids = new ArrayList<>();
    birthdaysKids.add(danny);
    birthdaysKids.add(ryan);

    for (Birthday b : birthdaysKids) {
        System.out.println(b.name + "'s birthday is on " + b.bdayKid + " and he is doing " + b.age +
                          " so, "+ (b.gift ? "he deserver a present" : "he does not deserve nothing"));
    }
```

output :

danny's birthday is on 22-10-2011 and he is doing 10 so, he deserver a present

ryan's birthday is on 10-05-2013 and he is doing 8 so, he does not deserve nothing

```
}

static class Birthday {
    private String name;
    private String bdayKid;
    private int age;
    private boolean gift;

    public Birthday(String name, String bdayKid, int age, boolean gift) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bdayKid = bdayKid;
        this.age = age;
        this.gift = gift;
    }

    public String getBdayKid() {
        return bdayKid;
    }

    public void setBdayKid(String bdayKid) {
        this.bdayKid = bdayKid;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean isGift() {
        return gift;
    }

    public void setGift(boolean gift) {
        this.gift = gift;
    }
}
```

}